# Force EE Smart Router to use Https instead of http protocol

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firefox, security

I have recently swapped my old router out for a new upgraded one that was sent to me through EE, I was wondering if there is any way to force it to use HTTPS either through code or via the settings. The normal Hub Settings and manager is located at a normal, non-secure http address, which I thought was weird seeing as its 2020, and nearly everything now uses HTTPS.. On my old router, if i tried to navigate to https://192.168.1.1 the address could not be found and it would not load anything. With this new one i can now navigate to the https version, but it is not the default option and Firefox developer edition is flagging this as a security concern. I'm just interested to learn more about computers, networking and tech in general. If I go to the https version and proceed past the warning, I can see that it allows me to navigate to the menu, does not require me to put in the router password which I thought was weird, but it is still showing in the padlock icon as a non secure site, which also has a self-signed certificate provide by BT(British Telecom).. Considering that this is the main access to all of my intenet I think its weird that Its not secure & any password I do choose for my router or POE security camera is visible and not difficult to access, Is it possible(Whithout the use of firefox plugin "HTTPSEverywhere").. To force the router to use https and maybe update the certificate to a non-self signed one.. Will add more info to this at a later stage and possible contact my ISP to see what they suggest also, just thought I'd ask it on here first and see what other peoples thoughts were.. I don't currently know the model number of the router but if I can find it i may post it on here.. If this is better suited to a different platform within StackOverflow please migrate it somewhere else, was just curious to get peoples input and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a setting in the UI to disable the non-secure HTTP service, and you weren't able to find any mention of it in your router's documentation, then it probably doesn't have a way to do that.

If someone has made Linux work on your router (like via a router firmware Linux distribution such as OpenWrt), then you could load Linux on your router and set up the web UI however you like.

To use TLS without a self-signed cert, you'd have to run your own firmware (such as OpenWrt) so that you can install your own root CA cert in the router's list of trusted root CA certs. No actual widely-trusted public CAs would issue a cert for a private IP address like 192.168.1.1, so you'll have to act as your own private root CA. Factory firmware is unlikely to let you install/replace certs like this, so you'll have to run your own firmware.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will look into researching OpenWrt. Also can't find any setting to disable broadcasting the SSID but thats another issue.. Will update the question or ask a new one after I have contacted my ISP and asked them why this is not secure by default...